# Spring MVC, AngularJS. Can't handle object values in JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

To handle pagination etc I decided to create an Object wrapper called ApiResponse which looks like this:

```
public class ApiResponse<T> {

    List<T> objectList;
    List<?> nestedElements;
    int currentPage;
    int offset;

// etc...

}
```

In Angular I have constructed a service as below:

```
App.factory('Apartment', ['$resource', function ($resource) {

    return $resource(
            'http://localhost:8080/Kamienica/api/v1/apartments/:id.json', 
            {id: '@id'},
            {
                'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:false},
                'update': {method: 'PUT'}

            }
    );
}]);
```

In controller I have:

```
            self.fetchAll = function() {

                var res = Apartment.query();

                console.log('=====   console.log(res);     =====');
                console.log(res);

                console.log('=====    console.log(res.objectList);      =========');
                console.log(res.objectList);
            };
```

When I print 'res' I get the object correctly but if want to reach its variables I get 'undefined' as you can see on the screenshot

[image: Browser Screenshot]

Previously in Spring controller I was returning a List <Apartment> 
instead if ApiResponse<Apartment> and It worked fine.

Bottom line is how I can reach objectList and other variables stored by the object?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Apartment.query();` data is fetched from the server in the background. At the time you call `console.log(res.objectList);` it has no property `objectList` because the data is not available yet.

Comment: Ok.. how to make it available?